# Fix header in scrolling material-ui popover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover

`material-ui` can have a fixed header and footer in a [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#scrolling-long-content) with long, scrolling content.

I wish to achieve this same effect, in a [popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/).

Taking the example:

```
<Popover>
  <Header>Fixed header</Header>
  <Content>long long long text</Content>
  <Footer>Submit button</Footer>
</Popover>
```

I want the scrollbar to appear in `Content`, while `Header` and `Footer` stay fixed in their popover.

I can achieve the desired result by setting a simple `style={{ height: 250 }}` on `Content`, but then I'd lose the dynamic sizing of the popover, which adjust its height according to the required size by its children but staying within the limits of the screen.

Is this even possible by using the library itself? If not, is anyone aware of any workarounds?

Comment: What is the reason for not using Dialog?

Comment: @RyanCogswell, popovers and dialogs serve different goals. I only compared with Dialog, because it has the content-scroll I'm trying to reproduce. I'm creating a select menu with search / filtering. An "advanced dropdown" so to say.

Comment: I was just curious on the type of Popover that would have header/footer with scrolling. Over the next few weeks, I'll be working on [enhancements to Select/Menu](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9893) to support a "dropdown" variant. This will involve some refactoring of code related to Popper/Popover. If you can share a sandbox showing the gist of what you're doing, I'd be curious to see it to add to the use cases I have in mind when working on the library enhancements.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, regarding the Select, it would be awesome if we could add the (multi) select menu on a Button instead of an `Input` as well. This is currently not possible. We can "open" it by clickin a linked button, but it still requires the `Input`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, About my use case, I've created something similar to the labels menu that github has. A search input on top, the select list in the middle. And a close button / other actions on the bottom. https://i.imgur.com/KnSBq5N.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by setting the `max-height` of the content in a dynamic way, you have to use `max-height: calc( 100vh - {headerHeigh - footerHeight})` you have to do `{headerHeigh - footerHeight}` manually, then your content should now how to handle the overflow with `overflow: auto;`, a working example:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid .popover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid .popover .content {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
}

footer {
  background: green;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="popover">
   <header>header</header>
   <div class="content">
    Lollipop pudding jelly bonbon caramels. Danish pastry chocolate cake. Macaroon oat cake marzipan powder bear claw
    sweet cake jujubes. Bear claw candy croissant oat cake cookie cotton candy fruitcake halvah. Carrot cake toffee
    powder topping. Cotton candy pudding chocolate bar croissant halvah danish jelly-o. Dessert cupcake marzipan
    pastry. Candy canes wafer donut. Dragée tart chocolate bar. Chupa chups oat cake candy sweet roll halvah biscuit
    brownie pastry lemon drops. Caramels danish soufflé fruitcake tootsie roll apple pie. Lemon drops soufflé tootsie
    roll cotton candy dessert liquorice.
   </div>
   <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="popover">
   <header>header</header>
   <div class="content">
    Lollipop pudding jelly bonbon caramels. Danish pastry chocolate cake. Macaroon oat cake marzipan powder bear claw
    sweet cake jujubes. Bear claw candy croissant oat cake cookie cotton candy fruitcake halvah. Carrot cake toffee
    powder topping. Cotton candy pudding chocolate bar croissant halvah danish jelly-o. Dessert cupcake marzipan
    pastry. Candy canes wafer donut. Dragée tart chocolate bar. Chupa chups oat cake candy sweet roll halvah biscuit
    brownie pastry lemon drops. Caramels danish soufflé fruitcake tootsie roll apple pie. Lemon drops soufflé tootsie
    roll cotton candy dessert liquorice.
    Lollipop pudding jelly bonbon caramels. Danish pastry chocolate cake. Macaroon oat cake marzipan powder bear claw
    sweet cake jujubes. Bear claw candy croissant oat cake cookie cotton candy fruitcake halvah. Carrot cake toffee
    powder topping. Cotton candy pudding chocolate bar croissant halvah danish jelly-o. Dessert cupcake marzipan
    pastry. Candy canes wafer donut. Dragée tart chocolate bar. Chupa chups oat cake candy sweet roll halvah biscuit
    brownie pastry lemon drops. Caramels danish soufflé fruitcake tootsie roll apple pie. Lemon drops soufflé tootsie
    roll cotton candy dessert liquorice.
    Lollipop pudding jelly bonbon caramels. Danish pastry chocolate cake. Macaroon oat cake marzipan powder bear claw
    sweet cake jujubes. Bear claw candy croissant oat cake cookie cotton candy fruitcake halvah. Carrot cake toffee
    powder topping. Cotton candy pudding chocolate bar croissant halvah danish jelly-o. Dessert cupcake marzipan
    pastry. Candy canes wafer donut. Dragée tart chocolate bar. Chupa chups oat cake candy sweet roll halvah biscuit
    brownie pastry lemon drops. Caramels danish soufflé fruitcake tootsie roll apple pie. Lemon drops soufflé tootsie
    roll cotton candy dessert liquorice.
    Lollipop pudding jelly bonbon caramels. Danish pastry chocolate cake. Macaroon oat cake marzipan powder bear claw
    sweet cake jujubes. Bear claw candy croissant oat cake cookie cotton candy fruitcake halvah. Carrot cake toffee
    powder topping. Cotton candy pudding chocolate bar croissant halvah danish jelly-o. Dessert cupcake marzipan
    pastry. Candy canes wafer donut. Dragée tart chocolate bar. Chupa chups oat cake candy sweet roll halvah biscuit
    brownie pastry lemon drops. Caramels danish soufflé fruitcake tootsie roll apple pie. Lemon drops soufflé tootsie
    roll cotton candy dessert liquorice.
    Lollipop pudding jelly bonbon caramels. Danish pastry chocolate cake. Macaroon oat cake marzipan powder bear claw
    sweet cake jujubes. Bear claw candy croissant oat cake cookie cotton candy fruitcake halvah. Carrot cake toffee
    powder topping. Cotton candy pudding chocolate bar croissant halvah danish jelly-o. Dessert cupcake marzipan
    pastry. Candy canes wafer donut. Dragée tart chocolate bar. Chupa chups oat cake candy sweet roll halvah biscuit
    brownie pastry lemon drops. Caramels danish soufflé fruitcake tootsie roll apple pie. Lemon drops soufflé tootsie
    roll cotton candy dessert liquorice.
    Lollipop pudding jelly bonbon caramels. Danish pastry chocolate cake. Macaroon oat cake marzipan powder bear claw
    sweet cake jujubes. Bear claw candy croissant oat cake cookie cotton candy fruitcake halvah. Carrot cake toffee
    powder topping. Cotton candy pudding chocolate bar croissant halvah danish jelly-o. Dessert cupcake marzipan
    pastry. Candy canes wafer donut. Dragée tart chocolate bar. Chupa chups oat cake candy sweet roll halvah biscuit
    brownie pastry lemon drops. Caramels danish soufflé fruitcake tootsie roll apple pie. Lemon drops soufflé tootsie
    roll cotton candy dessert liquorice.
   </div>
   <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! You're completely right. I tried it before, but it turned out a "pretty scrollbar" wrapper was messing that up. The final fix, `max-height: calc(100vh - 32px - footerPx - headerPx);`, the 100vh - 32px is the max-height of the `Popover`s `Paper` element.